# regular expression remove comment tag

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match-all

I want remove html comment tag

```
<!--QuoteEnd--></div><!--QuoteEEnd--> <!--hide me-->Abc<!--hide me-->
```

after remove

```
</div> Abc
```

Comment: Try to avoid using regexes to parse HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace("/(<!--.+?-->)/s", "", "<!--QuoteEnd--></div><!--QuoteEEnd--> <!--hide me-->Abc<!--hide me-->");
```

outputs

```
</div> Abc
```